# Best way to config linux kernel depending on yocto image

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I have a distro layer for yocto and want to have several packagegroups, like -dev, -release and maybe some other options. In packagegroup -dev i want to enable the magic-sysrq, which is enabled by an kernel config fragment.

What's the best way to to this? 
Should i make a recipe magic-sysrq.bb and use RDEPENDS_packagegroup-dev = "magic-sysrq" or should i make an append for the kernel recipe?

I'm unclear what's a nice way to add the fragment. Should i use simply SRC_URI or is there some special variable.

PS:
I'm using Pyro from the linux-xlnx kernel.

Comment: first change in the kernel and create a patch thenafter create a linux-ti_%.bbappend file for that patch

Comment: Yeah, that's clear. But when i have a release image, i don't want to make the append. But there's no way for deciding, if the append is applied for a given image or packagegroup

Comment: in your sources/meta-layer having GIT. take patch from that path then the patch having  both (.bbappend file and linux patches ). those are called as yocto patches.